# How to make test cases stable in Selenium backed Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does there exist any way to make test cases more stable? Sometimes a test case fails (and also it shows a "Timed out for waiting error") but when I re-run the same test case again after some time it does not throw an exception or error.

Comment: This is a "it depends" were your tests 100% reliable in the first place? I mean that in 100 runs they always passed?

Comment: Hi Artbristol,actually i am preparing a POC of a project which i am doing in Webdriver backed selenium.So for my case it is impossible for me to run it 100times as i have ample of test cases.

Comment: if you are doing a PoC then I would skip selenium backed webdriver and go straight for WebDriver

Comment: I am almost done with PoC,will switch to the Webdriver once this project is done.But for this only thing, apart from Sleep is there exist any other alternative,as the same problem will occur in Webdriver also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [there is](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits):

> Explicit Waits.
>   An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a
>   certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. The
>   worst case of this is Thread.sleep(), which sets the condition to an
>   exact time period to wait. There are some convenience methods provided
>   that help you write code that will wait only as long as required.
>   WebDriverWait in combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this
>   can be accomplished.

Comment: Hi Misha,actually i am preparing a POC(proof of concept) using Webdriver backed Selenium,is there any command in it to make Test cases more reliable and stable?As this is depleting the working of  my whole project (POC),gradually.

Comment: Yes, there is, and I gave you url to the code examples and documentation. The rudest alternative to it – is to `sleep(10)` function call in language of your choice right after you open any page.This way you will give every page 10 seconds to load all the elements you need before using them. This is slow, dirty and unreliable, but is the quickest fix for your POC.